# Configuring Spring Data Redis with Lettuce for Redis master/slave

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, lettuce

Using Lettuce, how do we configure Spring Data Redis running on host x at port 6379 and slave running on the same or different host but at port 6380?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a feature which [will be included](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/287) in the upcoming Spring Data Redis 2.1 release.
You would configure `LettuceConnectionFactory` similar to:

```
    LettuceClientConfiguration configuration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                                                    .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA)
                                                    .build();

    LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("x", 6379),
                                                    configuration);
```

Lettuce auto-discovers masters and replicas from a static (not managed with Redis Sentinel) setup.

Comment: What is this LettuceTestClientConfiguration class here ?  i went through some documentation but there isnt any easy way to configure and use Lettuce with Master Slave. I tried using StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnection but  again it needs RedisCodec as its parameter which makes it harder to use with different datatypes. I want to have RedisTemplate kind of abstraction for master slave setup, is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: That’s a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Configure the appropriate ReadFrom.

Comment: "SLAVE_PREFERRED"s documentation says "read preferred from slaves and fall back to master if no slave is not available.", does that mean if slave is busy serving another request then use MASTER ?

Comment: No, this means that if a replica is down (no replica configured in the topology, connection to the replica is disconnected), then reads are routed to the master.

Comment: ReadFrom.SLAVE is deprecated