# Configuring Spring Data Redis with Lettuce for ElastiCache Master/Slave

Tags: java, redis, amazon-elasticache, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have a Elasticache setup with one master and two slaves. I am still not sure how to pass in a list of master slave RedisURIs to construct a `StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnection` for `LettuceConnectionFactory`. I only see support for standaloneConfiguration with single host and port.

```
LettuceClientConfiguration configuration = LettuceTestClientConfiguration.builder().readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE).build();
LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(SettingsUtils.standaloneConfiguration(),configuration);
```

I know there is a similar question [Configuring Spring Data Redis with Lettuce for Redis master/slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875258/configuring-spring-data-redis-with-lettuce-for-redis-master-slave?answertab=votes#tab-top[1])

But I don't think it works for ElastiCache Master/Slave setup as currently the above code would try to use `MasterSlaveTopologyProvider` to discover slave ips. However, slave IP addresses are not reachable. So what's the right way to configure Spring Data Redis to make it compatible with Master/Slave ElastiCache? It seems to me `LettuceConnectionFactory` needs to take in a list of endpoints and use `StaticMasterSlaveTopologyProvider` in order to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, static Master/Slave with provided endpoints is not supported by Spring Data Redis. I filed [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-762) to add support for that.

You can implement this functionality yourself by subclassing `LettuceConnectionFactory`, creating an own configuration and `LettuceConnectionFactory`.

You would start with something like:

```
public static class MyLettuceConnectionFactory extends LettuceConnectionFactory {

    private final MyMasterSlaveConfiguration configuration;

    public MyLettuceConnectionFactory(MyMasterSlaveConfiguration standaloneConfig,
            LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig) {
        super(standaloneConfig, clientConfig);
        this.configuration = standaloneConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected LettuceConnectionProvider doCreateConnectionProvider(AbstractRedisClient client, RedisCodec<?, ?> codec) {
        return new ElasticacheConnectionProvider((RedisClient) client, codec, getClientConfiguration().getReadFrom(),
                this.configuration);
    }
}

static class MyMasterSlaveConfiguration extends RedisStandaloneConfiguration {

    private final List<RedisURI> endpoints;

    public MyMasterSlaveConfiguration(List<RedisURI> endpoints) {
        this.endpoints = endpoints;
    }

    public List<RedisURI> getEndpoints() {
        return endpoints;
    }
}
```

You can find all code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mp911de/67b63afe6873d0eb6be408a7a80fc890), not posting all code here as it would be a wall of code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply! I will give it a try.

Comment: The provided code works for ssl disabled cluster. Starting from redis 3.2.6, ElastiCache supports ssl. I already tried Redisson. It worked without any problem. So I am wondering if Lettuce already supports ssl enabled Master/Slave ElastiCache as well or plans to support it soon.

Comment: There’s a pull request in the making.

Comment: Thanks again! I applied the code change from the PR and it's working now.

Answer (score 6):

There have been further improvements in AWS and Lettuce making it easier to support Master/Slave.

One improvement that has happened recently in AWS is it has launched reader endpoints for Redis which distributes load among replicas: [Amazon ElastiCache launches reader endpoints for Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-elasticache-launches-reader-endpoint-for-redis/).

Hence the best way to connect to Redis using ***Spring Data Redis*** will be to use the primary endpoint (master) and reader endpoint (for replicas) of the Redis cluster.

You can get both of them from the AWS console. Here is a sample code:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE_PREFERRED)
            .build();
    RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration redisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration =
            new 
     RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration(REDIS_CLUSTER_PRIMARY_ENDPOINT, redisPort);
    redisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration.addNode(REDIS_CLUSTER_READER_ENDPOINT, redisPort);
    redisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration, clientConfig);
}
```